# LiveSass vscode extension compiles my .sass file into single line of code .css file

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code, sass

I just started watching sass tutorials and i have a small problem and it's not happening for my tutorial teacher so i don't know how to solve it.

It happens that when i write code in my **.scss** file everything looks fine but when i jump into **.css** file it all compiles into single line of code it doesn't matter even if i have 200 lines of sass code. So here i will post the code examples. By the way iam using Visual Studio Code extension called "Live Sass Compiler".

Here is example of **scss code**

```
$color: red;

body {
  background: $color;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 1rem;
}

header {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

And this is **css compiled code**:

```
body{background:red}h1{font-size:1rem}header{font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif}
```

Comment: You need to open the settings of *Live Sass Compiler* and set the value of `"format"` to `"expanded"`.

Comment: That solved the problem. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## To change the format of a compiled Sass file

1. Go to **Extensions** in vertical tool-bar on the left
2. Then click on the **gearwheel** of **Live Sass Compiler**
3. Then scroll till you see **Live Sass Compile > Settings: Formats**
4. Click on **Edit in settings.json** right below it
5. Set the value of `"format"` to `"expanded"` ("format": "expanded",)